# Curious - Pros and cons of saving user uploaded images with a common file extension (such as .tmp)?

Tags: php, mysql

So, when a user uploads an image I save the image information such as new name, original name, size and mime type in a mysql database table and store the image in file system and also I do rename(uniquely) the images with a common file extension(.tmp). 
For example -

`nice_pic.jpg(user uploads) -> 0c14549a484.tmp(in server file system)`. 
Now when i need to add the images in DOM, I just rename the image again with their original extension from database 
such as - `0c14549a484.tmp -> 0c14549a484.jpg`.

Someone told me that there are security advantages. But not sure is this naming-renaming process worth the advantages? Like to know with an explanation.

Comment: what kind of advantages did they claim it would bring you, exactly? I can't think of any particularly useful ones - if any at all. It's not like anyone should be poking around on the server and trying to open these files. And if they're only images and not executables then they can't run them. And changing the file extension doesn't change the content...so if the file contains a virus it'll still contain a virus after you change the name.

Comment: Files (including images) will be _temporarily_ uploaded to /tmp. You should then `move_uploaded_file` to a sensible location, and serve your image files from that location.

Comment: Is it reduces  the chance of accidentally execute any kind of file with malicious extension such as .exe?

Comment: who is going to be executing them, do you imagine? Again, people should not be poking around on the server normally. And I don't know what your server O/S is, but in Unix/Linux environments, the file extension is entirely irrelevant to whether the file is executable or not. if you don't want it to get executed, don't set the executable permission on it when you save it. Only Windows adheres to the convention that .exe means it's executable (although in practice other file types are as well, and from a command-line you can execute anything regardless of the extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cons:
This, in my opinion, adds a lot of extra overhead to save the data and, also, increases the length of your hash (you cant save as many files with a shorter file name.

Regarding execution, if you allow running uploaded files on the server, you should be already thinking of a sandboxed execution environment (i.e. Docker) to run the files. Allowing external files to modify system environment is a huge security flaw in 99.99% of all cases, no matter the file extension.

Additionally, if you are running something like google drive with thousands of photos, you are losing computing time (although insignificant) to this processing.

I cannot think of any noteworthy pros of this approach, so my suggestion would be to stick with industry standard methods for the file processing.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @Simas.